# jQuery onkeyup every first input of block

Tags: jquery

I have the following (simplified) HTML markup:

```
<div class="accordion">
    <div class="block">
        <input type="text" name="name1">
        <input type="text" name="name2">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <input type="text" name="name3">
        <input type="text" name="name4">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <input type="text" name="name5">
        <input type="text" name="name6">
    </div>
</div>
```

What I would like to do is target each first input field of each .block. I would expect this to work:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.block input:first-child', function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

This however does not output anything, so I tried the following:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.block input:first', function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

This does work, but only for the first input field.

How can I target each first input in every .block without having to target them by name because these are variable?

This is the actual HTML:

```html
<div class="accordion_nested">
 <h5>title</h5>
 <div class="block">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="field_113">
    title
   </label>
   <a href="#" class="question"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></a>
   <span class="question_block"><p><em>text here</span>
   <input type="text" name="field_113[0]" value="test test" placeholder="" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="field_114">
    title
   </label>
   <a href="#" class="question"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></a>
   <span class="question_block"><p><em>text here</span>
   <input type="text" name="field_114[0]" value="test test" placeholder="" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="block">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="field_113">
    title
   </label>
   <a href="#" class="question"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></a>
   <span class="question_block"><p><em>text here</span>
   <input type="text" name="field_113[1]" value="test test" placeholder="" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="field_114">
    title
   </label>
   <a href="#" class="question"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></a>
   <span class="question_block"><p><em>text here</span>
   <input type="text" name="field_114[1]" value="test test" placeholder="" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your first code works just fine when I tested it

Comment: Whats not working when `:first-child` selector is used.

Comment: Post actual HTML not _(simplified)_ otherwise `'.block input:first-child'` would work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to target `.form-group:first-child`'s input element

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.block .form-group:first-child input', function() {
  console.clear();
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Here I have remove irrelevant HTML(as it contained invalid HTML)

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '.block .form-group:first-child input', function() {
  console.clear();
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion_nested">
  <h5>title</h5>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="field_113[0]" value="test test" placeholder="" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="field_114[0]" value="test test" placeholder="" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `:first-child`, while `:first` matches only a single element, the `:first-child` selector can match more than one: one for each parent. This is equivalent to `:nth-child(1)`

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '.block input:first-child', function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
    <div class="block">
        <input type="text" name="name1">
        <input type="text" name="name2">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <input type="text" name="name3">
        <input type="text" name="name4">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <input type="text" name="name5">
        <input type="text" name="name6">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @vespino yes you posted that. But I added description on this and let you know that it is working :)

Answer (score 0):

The Current code working properly

its give first child `input` value of each `block key up`

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '.block input:first-child', function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="block">
    <input type="text" name="name1">
    <input type="text" name="name2">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <input type="text" name="name3">
    <input type="text" name="name4">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <input type="text" name="name5">
    <input type="text" name="name6">
  </div>
</div>
```